# How to filter android file chooser apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-implicit-intent, android-afilechooser

I am using below code to select the file from device

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent,1212);
```

The above code give below output

[image: sample out put]

Is there any way to remove or filter the apps shown in dialog? for e.g. I want to remove both `com.android.contacts` from the dialog.

Comment: `ACTION_PICK` does not use MIME types, but rather a data `Uri`. Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to choose content by MIME type.

Comment: Thank you Mark sir, but problem with ACTION_GET_CONTENT, it shows Dropbox, drive, etc even after adding intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);

Comment: Sure. That's because those are valid options for the user. There is no magic way to say "I only want file choosers", as "file chooser" is a marketing term, not a technical one.

Comment: there won't be any option to disable Dropbox,drive, apps..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent type `Intent.ACTION_PICK` makes the app to open all other apps which are capable of doing the action `Intent.ACTION_PICK`. I have noticed it when I removed photos app, it's option was not showing in above popup.